# Agregating a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

I try to find what I missed in the code to retrieve the value of "Last_Maintenance" in a table called "Interventions".
I try to understand the order rules of SQL and the particularities of subqueries without success.

Did I missed something, something basic or an important step?

```
---Interventions with PkState "Schedule_Visit" with the Last_Maintenance aggregation
SELECT Interventions.ID AS Nro_Inter, 
    --Interventions.PlacesList AS Nro_Place, 
    MaintenanceContracts.Num AS Nro_Contract, 
    Interventions.TentativeDate AS Schedule_Visit, 
    --MaintenanceContracts.NumberOfVisits AS Number_Visits_Contracts,
    --Interventions.VisitNumber AS Visit_Number,
    (SELECT MAX(Interventions.AssignmentDate) 
    FROM Interventions
    WHERE PkState = 'AE4B42CF-0003-4796-89F2-2881527DFB26' AND PkMaintenanceContract IS NOT NULL) AS Last_Maintenance --PkState "Maintenance Executed"
FROM Interventions
INNER JOIN MaintenanceContracts ON MaintenanceContracts.Pk = Interventions.PkMaintenanceContract
WHERE PkState = 'AE4B42CF-0000-4796-89F2-2881527ABC26' AND PkMaintenanceContract IS NOT NULL --PkState "Schedule_Visit"
GROUP BY Interventions.AssignmentDate,
    Interventions.ID,
    Interventions.PlacesList, 
    MaintenanceContracts.Num, 
    Interventions.TentativeDate, 
    MaintenanceContracts.NumberOfVisits,
    Interventions.VisitNumber
ORDER BY Nro_Contract
```

I try to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause in a sub query, I did not succeed. Clearly I am lacking some understanding.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJDIr.png)

The output of "Last_Maintenance" is the last date of entire contracts in the DB, which is not the desirable output. The desirable output is to know the last date the maintenance was executed for each row, meaning, for each "Nro-Contract". Somehow I need to aggregate like I did below.

In opposition of what mention I did succeed in another table.
In the table Contracts I did had success as you can see.

```
SELECT 
    MaintenanceContracts.Num AS Nro_Contract, 
    MAX(Interventions.AssignmentDate) AS Last_Maintenance
    --MaintenanceContracts.Name AS Place
    --MaintenanceContracts.StartDate, 
    --MaintenanceContracts.EndDate
FROM MaintenanceContracts 
INNER JOIN Interventions ON Interventions.PkMaintenanceContract = MaintenanceContracts.Pk
WHERE MaintenanceContracts.ActiveContract = 2 OR MaintenanceContracts.ActiveContract = 1  --// 2 = Inactive; 1 = Active
GROUP BY MaintenanceContracts.Num, MaintenanceContracts.Name, 
    MaintenanceContracts.StartDate, 
    MaintenanceContracts.EndDate
ORDER BY Nro_Contract
```

I am struggling to understanding how nested queries works and how I can leverage in a simple manner the queries.

Comment: For a better answer post some sample source data and the expected results. Also, refrain from posting source/results as screen captures in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixed up in how aggregation works. The `MAX` function will get a single `MAX` value over the entire dataset. What you're trying to do is get a `MAX` for each unique ID. For that, you either use derived tables, subqueries or windowed functions. I'm a fan of using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign a sequence number. If you do it correctly, you can use that row number to get just the most recent record from a dataset. From your description, it sounds like you always want to have the contract and then get some max values for that contract. If that is the case, then you're second query is closer to what you need. Using windowed functions in derived queries has the added benefit of not having to worry about using the `GROUP BY` clause. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    MaintenanceContracts.Num AS Nro_Contract, 
    --MaintenanceContracts.Name AS Place
    --MaintenanceContracts.StartDate, 
    --MaintenanceContracts.EndDate
    i.AssignmentDate as Last_Maintenance
FROM MaintenanceContracts 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *
            --This fuction will order the records for each maintenance contract.
            --The most recent intervention will have a row_num = 1
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PkMaintenanceContract ORDER BY AssignmentDate DESC) as row_num
        FROM Interventions 
    ) as i
        ON i.PkMaintenanceContract = MaintenanceContracts.Pk
        AND i.row_num = 1  --Used to get the most recent intervention.
WHERE MaintenanceContracts.ActiveContract = 2 
    OR MaintenanceContracts.ActiveContract = 1  --// 2 = Inactive; 1 = Active
ORDER BY Nro_Contract
;
```